# SQL query Timeout error in ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, timeout

I have an ASP.NET web app which will just show data from SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition, the data to the SQL Server is inserted every time from a windows tool which will be inserting records in a bulk.

When I view my reports am getting timeout error, so I applied `command timeout=0` in all SQL command `databind` to a grid. So it was keeping on loading when I close the current page and open another page I will get

> execute reader requires an open connection.
>   or
>   timeout error.

I don't know how to resolve this. I have also applied `Nolock` in my SQL queries in all joins but still I am getting this error. So I created two instances of the SQL database; one for the tool and another one for the web but still I get this timeout error.

Could you please help me resolve this.

Comment: Very likely, you have a query/stored procedure (ar any sql module) that is not optimized and/or for what the execution time is great that [command timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) (the defaut timeout is 30s). First, you should find that sql module and then you should try to optimize (start by looking at the execution plan). *Usually*, the `NOLOCK` hint is not a solution and it can hide (sometimes) the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....but i get timeout error sometimes for login page itself or some other page where a page which will have a single grid with 240 rows..or for a grid which shows 1000 records....i get timeout error...

Comment: You *could* have some blocking queries: run `sp_WhoIsActive` [download](http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry42453.aspx). Also, read (again) the first comment.

Comment: MR.bogdan sahlean once again thanks for your reply.....i run that patch who_is_active i didn't find anything happening...may be i don't know how to use that patch....who_is_active i also included actual execution plan and changed.. use master to my database name but still i don't understand how to use it...could you please help me....

Comment: If you look at the first comment from `sp_WhosIdActive`'s source code then you will find this link: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/tags/who+is+active/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

## Bigger timeout time?

Put this to your web.config;

```xml
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<httpRuntime appRequestQueueLimit="100" executionTimeout="60000" />
</system.web>
```